# PHP PDO get information by username

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Okay, i'm logged in as "Admin", the admin have information - money, xp.
I have the code:

```
$query = dbConnect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM players");
$query->execute();

foreach ($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    echo 'Name: '. $row['Name'] . '<br>Money: '.$row['Money'] . '<br>XP: '.$row['XP'];
}
```

And i have 2 users in mysql. How to do that information is received by the logged in person?

Comment: or you could just select the user whos currently logged in instead of selecting all rows looping them

Comment: i'm only started learning php, i don't know how to do

Comment: you start using `WHERE` clause. use the user id thats currently logged in, continue using prepared statements, most likely you wouldn't need to a loop since you'd only want that single users credentials

Comment: I get this error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound' in

Code:

$query = dbConnect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM players WHERE username=:username");
$query->execute();

foreach ($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    echo 'Name: '. $row['Name'] . '<br>Money: '.$row['Money'] . '<br>XP: '.$row['XP'];
}

Comment: I don't suppose `dbConnect()` creates a new PDO instance every time it is executed, does it? If so, you're doing it wrong. You need to connect once and then store the connection in a variable.

Comment: @Noyz you didn't bind anything in your prepared statement

Answer (score 3):

Just select the specific row (user credentials) using the currently logged in user.

*Assuming you're using sessions*:

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$connection = dbConnect();
$query = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM players WHERE username = ?');
$query->execute(array($username));

$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(!empty($result)) {
    // echo credentials
    // echo $result['Money']; // etc
}
```

Or with `->bindValue` with your named placeholder:

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$connection = dbConnect();
$query = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM players WHERE username = :username');
$query->bindValue(':username', $username);
$query->execute();

$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(!empty($result)) {
    // echo credentials
    // echo $result['username']; // etc
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Save the logged in user id in a normal variable or SESSION variable and use it in your where clause

```
//so first we save the logged-in user id when the user logs in
$_SESSION['UserID'] = //loggedin user id;

//we then use the user id we save in a where clause to get that specific user
$query = dbConnect()->prepare('SELECT * FROM players WHERE playerID = ?');
$query->execute([$_SESSION['UserID']]);

foreach ($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    echo 'Name: '. $row['Name'] . '<br>Money: '.$row['Money'] . '<br>XP: '.$row['XP'];
}
```

Comment: Putting `$_SESSION['UserID']` into a string like that wouldn't work. You would need to wrap it with curly braces `{$_SESSION['UserID']}`, however it's generally good practice to use bound parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a session variable with the user's ID `$_SESSION['id'] = 'user1'`

Then you can frame your SQL statement like this:

`SELECT * FROM players WHERE userid = ?`

Answer (score 1):

Use `bindValue()` to bind the value of `:sessionID` to the value of `$_SESSION['UserID']` or however your UserID is stored. It will make creating your queries a little easier, and you can iterate over all of the results from your query with a while loop.

```
$DBO = dbConnect();
$query = $DBO->prepare("SELECT * FROM players WHERE playerID=:sessionID");
$query->bindValue(':sessionID', $_SESSION['UserID'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
    //$results[] = $row;
    echo 'Name: ' . $row['Name'] . '<br>Money: '. $row['Money'] . '<br>XP: ' . $row['XP'];
}
```